# How do i get value from other class?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, dao, morphia

I am a bit confused about how the value passing from getter and setters.

Here I have 2 class

**Seller** and **contract** that I wanna pass seller.symbol value into Contract

seller

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(value = "S", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Seller {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String symbol;

    private String clearingVenue;

    private String description;

    private String address;

    private String city;


    private String term;

    private String state;

    private String zipCode;

    private String country;


    private boolean showUser;
```

...Getter and Setters

Contract

```
   package dao.contract;

import dao.seller.Seller;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import requests.CreateSellerRequest;
import requests.UpdateSellerRequest;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(value = "contracts", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Contract {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String symbol;

    private String description;

    private int size;

    private String delivery;

    private String contractName;

    private double volumeInc;

    private String facility;

    private boolean showUser;
    private String seller;

    private Seller sellers;
```

What is the best approach to do this ? Should I call getter in Contract like "seller object.symbol"
I wanna pass the symbol value into Contract: String seller. 
what is the best approach here to connect value from 2 tables?

**I need some suggestion. not sure how to approach this issue.**

Thanks

Comment: need some ideas? any comment would help ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is to use getter setter methods for private data members.
in Contract class just write . hope it will help you.

```
          String symbols=sellerObject.getSymbol();
```